# Xcode5 Google Admob sdk linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, admob, ios7, xcode5

When following Googles installation procedures https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ I am unable to get a build due to:

linker command failed with exit code 1

I've tried some basic obvious documented tips of yor: [Keep getting error messages when compiling newest version of admob on IOS6 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628249/keep-getting-error-messages-when-compiling-newest-version-of-admob-on-ios6-sdk)

Also tried getting rid of armv7s slice out of Valid Architectures.  No dice.  Anyone having any success getting this library installed on Xcode5 for BaseSDK: iOS 7.0?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Apparently I'm a horrible user (negative rank).  Anything wrong with the posed question?

Comment: You could check with Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6 if you think that could be the issue but I'm guessing that you either missed the framework or adding filed to the target or something similar. Without the full error I can't really tell what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'm thinking I've got to check with Xcode 4.6 even though this is going to be a pain in the ass (as the project is a leviathan of other libraries).  I've edited post with errors.  The AdSupport.framework is definitely added to my project per documentation.

Comment: odd... apparently this resolved the build issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726640/build-error-while-add-revmob-add-in-ios-app

adding the StoreKit framework seems to have helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was missing the Storekit.framework.  It is documented and I am an imbecile.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Comment: Ah Thanks!  I just dropped the SDK into my project with cocoapods thinking it would completely configure my project.